# Convert a GroupBy object (groupby().size) into a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dictionary, pandas-groupby

Here is my try at something simpler.

```
demo = pd.DataFrame(data=np.array([["APPLE", "APPLE", "APPLE", "MANGO", "MANGO"],
                             ["DOWN", "DOWN", "DOWN", "UP", "DOWN"]]))

demo = demo.T
demo.columns = ['FRUIT', 'DIRECTION']
```

Here is what the above data frame looks like

```
    FRUIT   DIRECTION
0   APPLE   DOWN
1   APPLE   DOWN
2   APPLE   DOWN
3   MANGO   UP
4   MANGO   DOWN
```

and now

```
labels = demo["DIRECTION"]
l, v = np.unique(labels, return_counts=True)
d = dict(zip(l, v))
print(d)
```

This gives me the unique counts of the 'DIRECTIONS' column.

```
{'DOWN': 3, 'UP': 2}
```

Now, what if I wanted to find the frequency of counts of 'FRUIT' column grouped by 'DIRECTION' column.

I did do this.

```
print(demo.groupby(['FRUIT', 'DIRECTION']).size())
```

This gave me,

```
FRUIT  DIRECTION
APPLE  DOWN         3
MANGO  DOWN         1
       UP           1
```

I have issues with the above output.

I wanted to be able to do the following:

a) APPLE has nothing in the UP direction, so I wanted that to show as 0.
like the table given below.

```
FRUIT  DIRECTION
APPLE  DOWN         3
       UP           0
MANGO  DOWN         1
       UP           1
```

b) I wanted to be able to create it to a dictionary like so

```
{'APPLE': {DOWN: 3, UP: 0}, 'MANGO': {DOWN: 1, UP: 1}}
```

Any other way to reproduce the above dictionary is also fine. I'm using Python 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Demo:

**Part `a`**

```
In [19]: x = demo.groupby(['FRUIT', 'DIRECTION']).size()

In [20]: x
Out[20]:
FRUIT  DIRECTION
APPLE  DOWN         3
MANGO  DOWN         1
       UP           1
dtype: int64

In [21]: idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product((df.FRUIT.unique(), df.DIRECTION.unique()))

In [22]: x.reindex(idx).fillna(0)
Out[22]:
APPLE  DOWN    3.0
       UP      0.0
MANGO  DOWN    1.0
       UP      1.0
dtype: float64
```

**Part `b`**

```
In [79]: r = x.reindex(idx).fillna(0)

In [80]: r.reset_index() \
          .groupby('level_0').apply(lambda x: dict(zip(x['level_1'],x[0]))) \
          .to_dict()
Out[80]: {'APPLE': {'DOWN': 3.0, 'UP': 0.0}, 'MANGO': {'DOWN': 1.0, 'UP': 1.0}}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. How do I accomplish part b? I'm sorry.. I'm still learning to use dictionaries.

Comment: @josh I was about to hit post, when I saw Max's answer with _exactly_ the same thing. I had no choice but to upvote.

Comment: @Abhishek, i've also added solution for the part `b` ;-)

Comment: @MaxU Thank you kind sir! How do you get this good? Any super in-depth books out there that you recommend?

Comment: @MaxU Any super in-depth books out there on Python that you recommend? or out of pure experience?

Comment: @Abhishek, my way of learning is - trying to __answer__ questions on SO. When you try to answer them you'll automatically search for/learn the things that you don't know yet. It takes time, but it's very efficient. And of course Python/Pandas online docs and tutorials are __very helpful__

Answer (score 3):

A simpler way would be to use `unstack` and `stack`

```
In [4403]: x = demo.groupby(['FRUIT', 'DIRECTION']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

**PART A**

```
In [4404]: x.stack()
Out[4404]:
FRUIT  DIRECTION
APPLE  DOWN         3
       UP           0
MANGO  DOWN         1
       UP           1
dtype: int64
```

**PART B**

```
In [4405]: x.to_dict('index')
Out[4405]: {'APPLE': {'DOWN': 3, 'UP': 0}, 'MANGO': {'DOWN': 1, 'UP': 1}}
```

---

Details

```
In [4406]: x
Out[4406]:
DIRECTION  DOWN  UP
FRUIT
APPLE         3   0
MANGO         1   1
```

Comment: Yeah, looks great!